# Using for loop with async in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, for-loop, asynchronous, waterfall

I have connected with mongodb and nodejs.
I have question about sav query results to list.

```
results = [];

for(i = 0; i<query.length; i++){
    db.collection(collectionName).find(query[i]).toArray(function(err, result){
        results[i] = result;
    });
}
```

I used **async.waterfall**  but it doesn't work very well... 
If you fixed this problem like me, would you please how to fix this?

query like this :

```
{
location:{
  $geoWithin : {
    $center: [[lng, lat], radian]}}, 
time : "time value" 
}
```

lng, lat, time are list..

Comment: why don't you use async-await?

Comment: What do you mean, "doesn't work very well"? What is unclear to you and needs to be clarified?

Comment: I do not understand "async" yet. I will look into asyn-await..

Comment: wait let me write an answer for you.

Comment: As a side node: For the most cases, querying database in a loop is not a good idea.

Comment: @AnandUndavia agreed.

Comment: thank you all.. I will try and study hard..!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what the query array holds, you are better off running a single query which uses the **[`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)** operator instead of looping through the query array and firing server requests for each query:

```
db.collection(collectionName).find({ '$or': query }).toArray((err, results) => {
    console.log(results);
});
```